# Migrating excel file in Mysql database Row type

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel

My problem is that some of the cell in the excel file is having an apostrophe and I'm thinking of solving my problem by using addwithvalue in my sql query. Iam migrating my excel file in mysql database

here is my code

```
 = "INSERT INTO tbl_personalinfo(" & _
                         "CardNumber," & _
                         "IDnumber," & _
                         "Fname," & _
                         "Lname," & _
                         "Mname," & _
                         "Gender," & _
                         "Bday," & _
                         "PhoneNo," & _
                         "Address," & _
                         "GuardianName," & _
                         "Relationship," & _
                         "GuardianNo" & _
                         ") VALUES (" & _
                        "''," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 1, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 3, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 2, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 5, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & Bday & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow, xCol + 2).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 7, xCol).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 6, xCol + 2).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 7, xCol + 2).value & "'," & _
                        "'" & xlWorkSheet.Cells(xRow + 8, xCol + 2).value & "')"
```

my excel file is like this so

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDAYd.jpg)

Comment: That is one of the many issues that SQL Parameters solve.  Use `Add` rather than `AddWithValue` though. Otherwise, you did not actually ask a question.

Comment: where could i add that?

Comment: You shiuld be able to escape the single quotes by using a replace on "'" with two single quotes "''"

Comment: Do you need to loop and add many cards or just one?  We have no idea how the sheet or db is defined.